# como incorporar validación de longitud en texbox dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿como puedo incorporar validación de longitud en texbox dinámicos cuando se de clic en un botón Guardar?

- Sabiendo que un input válido es aquel que no debe estar vació y debe contener 19 digitos

Con esta funcion JS valido mis inputs dinámicos que no estén vacíos

```
function validaInputs() {
    //Validacion ´de que no haya campos vacios
    var todoCorrecto = true;
    var formulario = document.enviaComision;
    for (var w = 0; w < formulario.length; w++) {
        if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {
            if (formulario[w].value == "") {
                console.log(w-1);
                var x = w - 1;

                alert('Por favor ingrese serie :: Fila ' + x + " ::");
                $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html('<center><img src="../Images/cancel.png" width="30px" height="30px"/><br/><br/><span style="font-size:12px;color:red">Ingrese serie en los campos vacios</span></center>');
                todoCorrecto = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (todoCorrecto == true) {
        $('#tabla1').hide();
        var text;
        var t = document.getElementById("tblTabla1"); //una tabla con id 
        var tdId = t.getElementsByClassName("valorId"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdInterno = t.getElementsByClassName("valorInterno"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdFactura = t.getElementsByClassName("valorFactura"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdArticulo = t.getElementsByClassName("valorArticulo"); // cada row tiene clase


        for (var i = 0; i < tdId.length; i++) {
            var x = i + 1; // Variable para comenzar conteo en 1
            var id = tdId[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
            var numeroInterno = tdInterno[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
            var factura = tdFactura[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
            var articulo = tdArticulo[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
            var serie = document.getElementById('numeroSerie-' + [x]).value; 


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ruta",
                data: { Fa: fac, Art: ar, Ser: serie, numeroInterno: numeroInterno },

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html('<center><img src="../Images/ok.png" width="30px" height="30px"/><br/><br/>' + data + '<br/><span style="font-size:12px;color:green">Series guardadas exitosamente</span></center>');

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

y necesito agregar una nueva validación, la anterior solo era para que no hubiera campos vacíos, la nueva validación ya la tengo pero no se como podría incorporarla para que valide también la longitud de los textbox dinámicos y es la siguiente

```
function validacionSeries(txt) {

    var m = $("#numeroSerie-" + txt).val();    
    var expreg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{19,19}$");

    if (expreg.test(m)) {
        $("#divError-" + txt).html("<span style='color:green'>Serie válida</span>");        
    } else {
        $("#divError-" + txt).html("<span style='color:red'>Serie no válida</span>");        
    };
};
```

todo empieza desde mi codigo

```
for (var j = 0; j < valorCantidad; j++) {
    contador = contador + 1;
    jQuery('#tblTabla1 tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    '<td align="center" class="valorId">' + contador + '</td>' +
    '<td align="center" class="valorInterno">' + valorInterno + '</td>' +
    '<td align="center" class="valorFactura">' + valorFactura + '</td>' +
    '<td align="center" class="valorArticulo">' + valorArticulo + '</td>' +
    '<td align="center"><input type="text" id="numeroSerie-' + contador + '" name="Serie" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" class="form-control" onblur="validacionSeries(' + contador + ');"/><div id="divError-' + contador + '"></div></td></tr>'

    );                
}
```

Comment: No indicas en ningún momento qué es lo que consideras válido y qué no. Quizá si pones cuál es un *input* válido y cuál es un *input* inválido la gente te pueda responder de forma apropiada.

Comment: @kikocorreoso los inputs validos son los que no deben estar vacios y que deben tener 19 digitos

Answer (score 2):

Yo, haría la llamada al método desde `validaInputs` de la siguiente forma:

```
function validaInputs() {
    //Validacion ´de que no haya campos vacios
    var todoCorrecto = true;
    var formulario = document.enviaComision;
    for (var w = 0; w < formulario.length; w++) {
        if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {
            if (formulario[w].value == "") {
                console.log(w-1);
                var x = w - 1;

                alert('Por favor ingrese serie :: Fila ' + x + " ::");
                $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html('<center><img src="../Images/cancel.png" width="30px" height="30px"/><br/><br/><span style="font-size:12px;color:red">Ingrese serie en los campos vacios</span></center>');
                todoCorrecto = false;
            }
        }
        //podrías llamar al método desde aquí
        //para iterar cada input y validarlo
        if(!validacionSeries(w)){
            todoCorrecto = false;
        }
    }        
    if (todoCorrecto == true) {
        $('#tabla1').hide();
        var text;
        var t = document.getElementById("tblTabla1"); //una tabla con id 
        var tdId = t.getElementsByClassName("valorId"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdInterno = t.getElementsByClassName("valorInterno"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdFactura = t.getElementsByClassName("valorFactura"); // cada row tiene clase
        var tdArticulo = t.getElementsByClassName("valorArticulo"); // cada row tiene clase


        for (var i = 0; i < tdId.length; i++) {
            var x = i + 1; // Variable para comenzar conteo en 1
            var id = tdId[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
            var numeroInterno = tdInterno[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
            var factura = tdFactura[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
            var articulo = tdArticulo[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
            var serie = document.getElementById('numeroSerie-' + [x]).value; 


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ruta",
                data: { Fa: fac, Art: ar, Ser: serie, numeroInterno: numeroInterno },

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html('<center><img src="../Images/ok.png" width="30px" height="30px"/><br/><br/>' + data + '<br/><span style="font-size:12px;color:green">Series guardadas exitosamente</span></center>');

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Y al método de `ValidacionSeries(txt)` le haría esta modificacion:

```
function validacionSeries(txt) {
    var m = $("#numeroSerie-" + txt).val();    
    var expreg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{19,19}$");
    if (expreg.test(m)) {
        $("#divError-" + txt).html("<span style='color:green'>Serie válida</span>");
        return true;
    } else {
        $("#divError-" + txt).html("<span style='color:red'>Serie no válida</span>");
        return false;
    };
};
```

**EDIT**
Si no se recibe correctamente el parámetro `x` mueve mas arriba el `if` de esta manera quedaría:

```
for (var w = 0; w < formulario.length; w++) {
    if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {
        if (formulario[w].value == "") {
            console.log(w-1);
            var x = w - 1;

            alert('Por favor ingrese serie :: Fila ' + x + " ::");
            $("#mensajeRespuesta1").html('<center><img src="../Images/cancel.png" width="30px" height="30px"/><br/><br/><span style="font-size:12px;color:red">Ingrese serie en los campos vacios</span></center>');
            todoCorrecto = false;
        }
        if(!validacionSeries(w)){
            todoCorrecto = false;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: y el parámetro que envió de la función validaInputs() a la función validacionSeries puede ser la x?

Comment: si, en caso que no reciba el parámetro `x` puedes mover el `if` unas lineas más arriba.

Comment: gracias bro por la ayuda =)

Comment: Glezz siempre regresa falso la validación    if(!validacionSeries(txt)){ todoCorrecto = false;   }, aunque ya estén correctos los textbox

Comment: @Ivxn te devuelve la variable `todoCorrecto = false` si tienes el código del edit es porque un campo esta entrando en la condición `if (formulario[w].value == "") {` y en ese segmento esta asignando a la variable `falso`

Comment: Otro error posible es que al asignarle `x = w -1` volverá a falso porque en cuanto entre en el primer ciclo cambiaría el valor de `todoCorrecto`, esto es porque a `x` le estas diciendo que en la primera iteración `w=0` entonces `x = 0 - 1 => x=-1`

Comment: No, quite la validación del  if(!validacionSeries(txt)){ todoCorrecto = false; } y la coloque al nivel de la condicion if (formulario[w].type == 'text') {...} y tambien al nivel del ciclo for, pero sigue enviando false

Comment: Glezz creo que si es el valor de x, pero como puedo cambiarlo o tendria que crear otra variable?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42225/discussion-between-juankglezz-and-ivxn).